# How to get target score for match in group of 3 to qualify for next round?

Tags: cricket

How to get the target score for a match if one team in tournament Team A has a 0.4 net runrate while playing 1 match, another team B has a 0.0 net run rate in 2 matches and a third team C in league has a -0.3 run rate in 1 match. Now how to get the target score for team A and team C to qualify for the next round in their next match?

Answer (score -1):

First and foremost thing you need to know is that you cannot calculate the target score only having the NRR data. You would require the previous scores as well. NRR in league stage is calculated based on the scores of each matches. So, we need the scores of the previous matches.

Let me assume some virtual scores based on the NRR you mentioned:

- **Match 1: Team A vs Team B** | Team A 280/4 (50), Team B 260/7 (50) | Team A won by 20 runs | NRR: Team A +0.4, Team B -0.4
- **Match 2: Team B vs Team C** | Team C 238/9 (50), Team B 239/3 (47) | Team B won by 7 wickets | NRR: Team B 0.0, Team C -0.3

Here comes the calculation for the next match. Let's assume only top team will qualify to the next round and also assume that Team C win the last match so that every team has 1 win in their bag.

- Team A batting first scored 250/8 (50): Team C have to reach the target in 46 overs to qualify

  ```
  |--------|--------------------|------------------------|---------|
  |  Team  |  Runs for (Overs)  |  Runs against (Overs)  |   NRR   |
  |--------|--------------------|------------------------|---------|
  |   A    |      530 (100)     |        511 (96)        |  -0.02  |
  |--------|--------------------|------------------------|---------|
  |   B    |      499 (97)      |        518 (100)       |   0.00  |
  |--------|--------------------|------------------------|---------|
  |   C    |      489 (96)      |        489 (97)        |  +0.02  |
  |--------|--------------------|------------------------|---------|
  ```

PS: For NRR calculation related clarity please go through [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Net_run_rate).